# WPF binding and pointers

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a WPF application that contains some `Window`s with few `UserControl`s and a `Coordinator` object. The window and all its user controls are pointing to an object, which instance is in the Coordinator, by their DataContext.

The problem is that I want to change this object (e.g. create new object()) in the Coordinator but I want all the `DataContext`s  to point to the new object.
I tried to send the object by ref to the window constructor but it didn't help.

Any idea about how can I rewrite the memory location that all pointers are pointing to?
(I don't want to replace the properties in object since it's a lot of work nor to use a middle object that points to the replaced object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to send the object by ref to
>   the window constructor but it didn't
>   help. any idea about how can I rewrite
>   the memory location that all pointers
>   are pointing to?

It's normal because, even if you change the object the reference is pointing to, your user controls have no way to know that something has changed : you have to notify them.

You have two solutions to do so :

- make your Coordinator implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** and raise **NotifyPropertyChanged** when the object reference changes,
- make your object available via a **DependencyProperty** and use a property wrapper.
  When changed the **DependencyProperty** will automatically notify its observers.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I missed something, you are using datacontext in your application so when you create a new object, can you not set the datacontext to the new object and it will be bound to all of your user controls.

```
ClearValue(DataContextProperty);

DataContext = NewlyCreatedObject;
```

Comment: i simplify my question in order to explain the problem actually i have a lot of windows with different datacontexts each with the above description hence i would like to change all the objects from the Coordinator and avoid changing the windows properties